# Asymptotic expansion of scaled Hermite polynomial

Tags: hermite-polynomials

I have a scaled probabilist's Hermite polynomial:
\begin{equation}
H_n(ax)e^{-bx^2}
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are both complex numbers. What is the asymptotic limit of this expression as $n \to \infty$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Asymptotic expansion for physicists Hermite polynomials as $n\to\infty$: [yikes](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/HermiteH/06/01/04/)

Comment: Very useful. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is not a simple problem. The large-$n$ asymptotics of the Hermite polynomial depends heavily on the location of $ax$ in the complex plane. You can re-express them in terms of parabolic cylinder functions (http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.15.E28) and apply the results of the paper F. W. J. Olver, Uniform asymptotic expansions for Weber parabolic cylinder functions of large orders, J. Res. Nat. Bur. Standards Sect. B 63B (1959), pp. 131–169.

Comment: This is informative. Thanks! For now, I need the expansion at small $|x|$. The simplest form seems to works ok for the $a$ values I'm using. I might need different form at other parameter values.